# Text color selector doesn't work on android 4

Tags: android, button, android-text-color

I try to apply simple text color selector for all of my buttons. I override default Button style and use it in my application theme (AppTheme). It works as expected on android 5 and up but it doesn't work on android 4. Check out my code.

[image]

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/btn_text_color_selector</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**btn_text_color_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_enabled="false"></item>
    <item android:color="@color/colorAccent"></item>
</selector>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Kalės vaikas" />
```

Comment: Hey as am not seeing , how you are setting color in your button,  check your post

Comment: AppTheme changes default Button style. It is the main theme of my app.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `btn_text_color_selector.xml`, why don't you just add  android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" :

**Like this**

```
 <Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Kalės vaikas" />
```

*This will maintain all the platforms .*

Comment: Because that would be boiler plate code. I would need to add that line to every single button of my app. This is redundant. Also the text color is not just a color, it's a selector and that means text changes color depending on button state.

Comment: It's redundant that;s true @Elgis, but it executes what you want , sometimes we consider output,